# Reviewing the Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml files for a basic nodejs mysql project

Tags: mysql, node.js, dockerfile, docker

I'm new to docker and after much research and stufy I've created a sample application and would like it to be reviewed in case if I'm missing any corner or if there's redundant information that can be simplified.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN npm install

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

MySQL is getting initialized through schema.sql

```
version: '3'

services:
  database:
    image: "mysql:5.7"
    container_name: "mysql"
    ports:
      - "6603:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    environment:
      DATABASE_HOST: database
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
      MYSQL_USER: mysql
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password

  service:
    build: .
    image: "node"
    container_name: "nodejs"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - database
    links:
      - database
    environment:
      DATABASE_HOST: database
      MYSQL_PORT: 3306
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
      MYSQL_USER: mysql
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    restart: on-failure
```

**index.js**

It has some delay, that basically waits for the mysql to become fully alive.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var mysql = require('mysql');

    var con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
        user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
        password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE
    });

    con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Database Connected!");

        var http = require('http');

        //create a server object:
        http.createServer(function (req, res) {
            res.write('Hello World!'); //write a response to the client
            res.end(); //end the response
        }).listen(8080); //the server object listens on port 8080

        console.log("Listening at 8080");
    });
}, 10 * 1000);
```

I had one file in docker-compose.yml which I removed assuming it's not required.

```
#    volumes:
#      - .:/src
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably it's better to you concrete `node` version.

Also, you can try [`expressjs`](https://expressjs.com/) framework.

I have got simple example of `Dockerfile` [here in this sub-directory of my repository](https://github.com/andrzejsydor/docker/tree/master/nodejs).
But that is without Docker Compose and connection to any database.